# Having trouble with RSpec 3.1.0 and has_many through relationship with Ruby-on-Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, has-many-through, has-many

I am trying to use RSpec to test my relationships between Models. I have two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles
end
```

and

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end
```

with a through class of:

```
class UserRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

My RSpec code is:

```
describe User do
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:user_roles) }
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:roles).through(:user_roles) }
end
```

Both of these throw errors:

1) User should have many :user_roles
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many(:user_roles) }
       expected # to respond to `has_many?`
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in '

2) User 
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to have_many(:roles).through(:user_roles) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `through' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Has:0x007fe1cd003ac8>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:50:in`block (2 levels) in '

No matter what I try I can't seem to get these to work. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using Shoulda. You could also solve this problem by programming your own matchers.